# Computer goes haywire and creates a shield dome over a city. Female protagonist fights to shut it down

Tags: story-identification

I'm trying to recall a novel with a female protagonist and her male friend. The main premise is that a city or town gets controlled by a computer system that just recently comes online. It malfunctions (goes rogue) and the system reroutes power from an old folks home and putting a shield over the town to control the weather. Unfortunately this results in some of the residents dying.

The mains characters end up having to break into the mainframe to shut the system down. Her friend dies when he is shot with a laser from the system.

This book was (probably) for young adults and read it when I was in high-school in 2010.

Comment: Have a look at the checklists here ([How to ask a good story-ID question?](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)) to improve this. For starters, it sounds like the main characters are female. Can you describe them better? What are their ages? What did they look like? Why do they want to break the mainframe? How do they do it? Is anyone trying to stop them? How is the shield generated? How do they know it's gone rogue? Is this for young adults or adults? Do you remember the character's names? Where and when did you read/watch/see this?

Comment: Updated post to reflect changes.

Comment: Close vote retracted. Downvote retracted. Any more info from that checklist? What language did you read it in? Was the main character white? Do you recall the book cover?

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/244416/1970s-novel-about-computer-hackers-extorting-a-city (which is newer but has an accepted answer)

Answer (score 5):

Could this be [The Tomorrow City](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/682611.The_Tomorrow_City) by Monica Hughes?

> C-Three, the computer, is programmed to make the city of Thompsonville
>   an ideal place to live in. But disaster threatens as the computer uses
>   increasingly ruthless means to discard all that is old and useless.
>   Caro and David are aware of the horrors, but can they alert the others
>   in time?

[image]